# Aframe - displaying a dynamic web page on a canvas over a scene

Tags: javascript, url, canvas, aframe

I have a scene and would like to connect a menu coming from an external URL. I understand that this is done through displaying over a Canvas element, but little info is given on the subject. Could someone share their experience or a recipe to make that happen, or perhaps suggest a useful component?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are looking to do? Overlay HTML over A-Frame, render HTML on a canvas as a texture, full webpages in A-Frame?

Comment: I presume that overlaying a render of an html as a texture can be quite slow, so going with the first option of overlaying an HTML - from a live served site within the Aframe window.